# Alternative to Expect for ActiveState Perl

Tags: perl, expect

As per the Expect perldoc, this module is not available with ActiveState Perl.

the perldoc says one alternative is to use Cygwin. I don't really have the option of installing this.

Any other suggestions?

I need to interactively control the powerShell using perl program.

Your help will be highly appreciated!!
Any input please!!

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this Perlmonks discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=662535) of the same issue.

It appears that [`IO::React`](http://search.cpan.org/~garrow/IO-React-1.03/React.pm) offers similar functionality for anything that can be connected to a handle (see the core module [`IO::Handle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html)).

Comment: IO::React used along with Proc::Spawn. Proc::Spawn is not available with Window ActiveState Perl http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Proc-Spawn/

Comment: Yes I understand that solution with other scripting languages are available for Windows platform. I am mainly looking for expect with ActiveState Perl.

Comment: @rpg, I actually tried installing `IO::React` on Windows and it installed with no problem (Strawberry Perl 5.16).  It didn't require `Proc::Spawn` as a dependency.  You should be able to get it working on ActiveState as well, if not through PPM then through CPAN.

Comment: No, it may not work. IO::Reach require file handle. How will you pass the filehandle to it? Please see the example code written in IO::React